# square .net api using SqPaymentForm is not returning the nonce

Tags: .net, api, sdk, square

Out website is still using Square-DotNet-SDK/11.0.0 v2

This website is for a community swimming pool and we haven't used the website since last fall.

Today when I am testing it for the season we are not getting the nonce. Has something changed?

I am not familiar with this code and am trying to help.

```
    var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
        // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
        // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
        // which is also available there.
        applicationId: 'the id', 
        inputClass: 'sq-input',
        cardNumber: {
            elementId: 'sq-card-number',
            placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
        },
        cvv: {
            elementId: 'sq-cvv',
            placeholder: 'CVV'
        },
        expirationDate: {
            elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
            placeholder: 'MM/YY'
        },
        postalCode: {
            elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
            placeholder: 'Postal Code'
        },
        inputStyles: [
            // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
            // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
            // input style below.
            {
                fontSize: '14px',
                padding: '3px'
            },
            // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
            // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
            // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
            {
                mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
                fontSize: '18px',
            }
        ],
        callbacks: {
            cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
                var errorDiv = document.getElementById('TextBoxError');
                if (errors) {
                    errorDiv.value = "";
                    errors.forEach(function (error) {
                        errorDiv.value = error.message + " " + errorDiv.value;
                    });
                    var EnableCharge = document.getElementById('ButtonChargeCard').disabled = true; //'ButtonChargeCard'

                } else {
                    // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
                    var nonceField = document.getElementById('cardNonce');
                    nonceField.value = nonce;
                    var nonceTextBoxField = document.getElementById('TextBoxNonce');
                    nonceTextBoxField.value = nonce;
                    var EnableCharge = document.getElementById('ButtonChargeCard').disabled = false; //'ButtonChargeCard'
                }
            },
            unsupportedBrowserDetected: function () {
                // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
            }
        }
    });
```

I used the SqPaymentForm which always supplies the nonce and i am not getting one.

Comment: Could Square be having any issues? Do I have to update from version 11?

Comment: I did verify that other APIs are working such as locationsapi.listlocations

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get our aspx vb.net 4.7.2 website to use the Square Web SDK.
It required creating a new website from scratch and making the payment in 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause the `SqPaymentForm` is now retired. I've sent the migration guide to help you move to the Web Payments SDK.